# What do you call a building, or rooms within it, where doctors see their patients?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, american-english, british-english

My understanding is as follows. Is this universally agreed?

The OED sense 2a of ***surgery*** explains its use to describe the room where a doctor sees his patients. The OED gives no indication that this sense is exclusively used in Britain.

> 2a. The room or office in a general practitioner's house or a health
>   centre where patients are seen and treatment is prescribed; the
>   regular session at which a doctor receives patients for consultation
>   in his surgery.

Nowadays where GPs work in group practices the individual rooms used by each are rarely, in my experience called surgeries. We refer to the entire building where our doctors practice as *the surgery*. "*When you go to the village, could you call in at the surgery and collect my prescription*".

As we sit in our doctors' waiting room, when our turn arrives an electronic sign with the patient's name on says 'please go to room 5'. Hence the place where you encounter the doctor is not strictly a surgery, but nowadays a room within a surgery. It is historically known as a *consulting room*.

As the OED explains, and as can be seen from the OED definition, *a surgery* is also a session during which the doctors are available to see patients. e.g. *morning surgery starts at 8.00am; afternoon surgery at 3.00pm*.

The OED also goes on to explain how people such as Members of Parliament, Accountants etc hold *surgeries*, borrowing the word from the medical profession.

> 1846   Bentley's Misc. June 549   A small den [Dr. Faunce] called ‘the
>   surgery’.
>
> 1862   M. E. Braddon Lady Audley's Secret III. vii. 200   The door of
>   the little surgery was ajar... The surgeon was standing at the
>   mahogany counter, mixing a draught in a glass measure.
>
> 1872   L. P. Meredith Teeth (1878) 252   In some localities, the
>   dentists..crowd their surgeries together in the same building.
>
> 1938   F. B. Young Dr. Bradley Remembers i. 1   Between six and
>   eight..Dr. Bradley ‘took’ his evening surgery as usual.
>
> 1944   J. D. Carr Till Death do us Part xi. 113   I've got to be
>   back..for surgery at half-past ten.
>
> 1964   D. Francis Nerve v. 73   I'm late for surgery... Those pills
>   ought to keep him quiet.
>
> 1975   ‘J. Bell’ Victim ii. 23   Dr. Swallow was dealing with his
>   morning surgery.

Comment: About half of your examples are not using surgery in the sense of a room, but in the sense of the act of hacking someone up.

Comment: Note that 'the surgery', whether as a doctor's office or anything else, is just not used in AmE.

Comment: 1. What is the question? Is it about the word *surgery*, as the body of the question seems to suggest, or about a term for the MI Room? Can you be more specific?

Comment: 2. Why not set aside the notion that *surgery* is about and only about "treatment by incision" which it is not?

Comment: @Oldcat None of the OED examples refer to 'the act of hacking someone up'. The two meanings of *surgery* to which 2a relates are as the name of the building where doctors see their patients, and as a session of seeing patients (which may simply involve looking in their throats and asking them to say *ah*!) For some reason, and this is a new discovery to me, these two senses of *surgery* are not used in America. I do seem to recall from my time in Australia that they used *surgery* in the same way we do.

Comment: @Kris But OED sense 2a is not about any form of 'treatment'. It concerns either the name of the building, or a treatment **session** involving any number of patients - e.g. *morning surgery was very busy today*.

Comment: Obviously you are still on that same wavelength. Please get the gist of my comment.

Comment: @Kris I note your remarks.

Comment: @Kris because there is no other commonly understood and unambiguous word for "treatment by incision", whereas consultation is, well, *consultation*, regardless of where or by whom it is performed. You can't co-op the particular word into a general sense, it is simply not useful to do that. Use the general word that already exists, for its many uses.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This usage is not a universal in modern English.

American dialects typically refer to a doctor's *office* as the building and/or room used for examination.  The building may also be a *clinic*.  The room itself may be called an *examination room* or, in most informal spoken English, an *exam room*.  If the doctor is practicing within a hospital, they have an *office* in the hospital.

Surgery is a specialized term in the USA that typically describes only the branch of medicine related to cutting people open for repairs or examination.

From the American Heritage Dictionary on surgery:

> 1. The branch of medicine that deals with the diagnosis and treatment of injury, deformity, and disease by the use of instruments.
>      2.
>      a. Treatment based on such medicine, typically involving the removal or replacement of diseased tissue by cutting: The athlete had surgery on his knee.
>      b. A procedure that is part of this treatment; an operation: The doctor performed three surgeries this morning.
> 2. An operating room or a laboratory of a surgeon or of a hospital's surgical staff: How long has the patient been in surgery?
> 3. *Chiefly British*
>      a. A physician's, dentist's, or veterinarian's office.
>      b. The period during which a physician, dentist, or veterinarian consults with or treats patients in the office.

Comment: It surprises me that you would call it an *office* as the room typically contains so much more than office equipment, -medical equipment, an examination couch, etc. Indeed it is a place where minor surgical procedures can be carried out. Our *surgery*, from which six General Practitioners operate, does have an *office*, but that is where the receptionist sits, as well as the staff who run the clerical functions of the practice. Seems as if we remain two nations separated by a common language.

Comment: @WS2: I'd call the room where the doctor talks to and looks at patients an *examination room*, and not a *doctor's office* (the doctor's office would consist of all the rooms used by a doctor, which might contain a waiting room, examination rooms, a file room, and so forth). But I wouldn't count on all Americans using the same terminology in this regard.

Comment: @PeterShor Do you use the term *health centre*? A larger ones over here, with perhaps twenty doctors, would tend to be known as a *health centre*.

Comment: @WS2: It wouldn't be called *health center* here. We definitely have those things, but the only terms I can think of for them are *group practice* or *medical building*, neither of which is a perfect fit.

Comment: In Northern California at least, *health center* isn't a common term.  I doubt I've ever heard it used here.  *Clinic* would be more typical.  *Medical center* is sometimes used for large, non-hospital medical facilities.

Comment: @PeterShor we also use the term *group practice*. But [this](http://www.bracknellurgentcare.co.uk/) is a new arrival on the health scene here. It is more than a doctor's practice but less than a hospital. This one was built because it is ten miles from the nearest hospital and Accident & Emergency Unit.

Comment: Just to agree: *surgery* is either the OR, or the activity performed in it. Either way, scalpels will be involved. You visit the doctor at her *office* (if she's the only MD there) or her *clinic* (if multiple doctors share the space). The actual room with the exam table, scale, etc. is called the *exam room* or *examination room*. IME, *medical center* is a hospital plus all the medical facilities that have grown up around it. *Health center* is either the free clinic on a college campus, or it's an "alternative medicine" facility.

Comment: @Marthaª: Interesting.  I'm a native AmE speaker, and I never thought of *surgery* as referring to the operating room.  To me it's the act of operating on a patient, and never refers to a physical place.  When you say *the patient is in surgery*, I don't understand that as giving her  location, but just to mean that she is undergoing a medical operation.  I guess I see *in surgery* as being analogous to *in pain* or *in labor*; it describes a person's state of being, not their location.

Comment: @NateEldredge And all that would be the case in Britain too. Being *in surgery* means undergoing an operation. But used with an article *surgery* can and mostly does refer either to the building from which a group of doctors practice, or to an open session - *morning surgery starts at 8.00am*. As Jessa points out in her answer it is meaning 3 in Merriam Webster.

Comment: Partly the confusion could stem from the fact that dentists actually do cut in to the body in their offices, and veterinarians may well do that also but General Practitioners might never cut in to any bodies except for extremely minor procedures such as biopsies (performed with a simple instrument, not a deep invasion of the body, which would require much more preparation and equipment). The folks who actually perform surgery are properly called *Surgeons*, and they are highly trained and specialized. You could go your whole life without ever consulting one. Can particular terms stay specific?

Answer (score 8):

I have always heard the building as a whole called the "doctor's office", and the particular room where the doctor sees you the "examination room".

Comment: There's also the term _clinic_, often used when more than one doctor works there.

Comment: In Britain a *clinic* is usual something of a specialist nature that is set up for the purpose - such as an *ante-natal clinic*. There are also *post-natal clinics* run by midwives where new-born babies are taken for regular check-ups.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the widely used "consultation room", although many dictionaries apparently have "consulting room" instead.

Comment: In Britain it is known as a *consulting room* - sometimes parodied as an *insulting room*!

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker, the word *practice* came to mind. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practice):

3. A place where a professional service is provided, such as a general practice. *She ran a thriving medical practice.*

Comment: Yes. We also speak about a *doctors' practice*. But the term *practice* is rarely applied to the building or the address from which they operate.

Comment: Old Joke: One Doctor says to another, "*When do we get to stop* practicing *medicine and start doing it for real?*"

Answer (score 0):

Doctors see their patients in: doctor's offices, outpatient facilities, hospitals and clinics. Surgery is Chiefly British (unless you are in the operating room, being operated on by a surgeon.) I heard some doctors still make house calls.

Comment: House calls are rare, but for infirm people and in appropriate circumstances, especially if you are well known to the doctor, some will do that. When our children were little, about 30 years ago, our village doctor would sometimes call by if they were sick.

Comment: Funny how "call" nowadays means telephone call and the meaning of "visit" has basically vanished.