# Seemingly quintessentially British non-medical meaning for "surgery"

Tags: meaning

Due diligence: I have Googled the word "surgery," and I have reviewed a couple of dozen past questions on this site related to the word "surgery." I have not found a satisfactory answer to the question which follows.

I hail from the United States. I recently had occasion to consult the website of the British Parliament. I noticed that in the sections for individual members the word "surgery" would often occur along with a listing of days and times. Internal evidence suggested that I should interpret "surgery" to mean "office hours" -- i.e., when a person could expect to find the M.P. in the office.

First of all, is my conception correct?

If so, how did "surgery" come to have this non-medical connotation?

Thanks to all who have offered, or will offer, answers.

Comment: I always assumed it was because you go along and tell them your problems, analogous to going to the doctors.

Comment: [This question may be of interest](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252696/what-do-you-call-a-building-or-rooms-within-it-where-doctors-see-their-patient).

Comment: @MartinSmith "MP, it hurts when I do this." "*Well don't do that!*"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The term ***[surgery](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/surgery)*** has been adopted outside clinical contexts by analogy in meaning:

> - (Britain) Any arrangement where people arrive and wait for an interview with certain people, similar to a doctor's surgery.
>
>   - *Our MP will be holding a surgery in the village hall on Tuesday.*'

***[Surgery](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Surgery+(politics)) (politics):***

> - A political surgery (in British politics) or clinic ***is a series of one-to-one meetings that a Member of Parliament (MP) may have with his or her constituents, at which a constituent may raise issues of local concern.***  The issues may relate to local issues (street crime, litter, a request for intervention by the MP on behalf of the constituent with local or national government) or it could deal with national policy matters.

(The Free Dictionary)

The expression ***[political surgery](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=political%20surgery%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpolitical%20surgery%3B%2Cc0)*** appears to be from the early 19th century according to Google books.

Comment: \ Thank you for your prompt response, which  I accept. If you have any idea as to how "surgery" came to have this meaning, do feel free to augment your answer. I have one other iron in the fire: the excellent British website, World Wide Words, to which I shall submit my query after a decent interval.

Comment: The use of surgery in politics (a meeting with a politician) is by analogy in meaning with a visit to a doctor.

Comment: I don't think it's really called a "political surgery" in English but simply "surgery", or MP's surgery [*Most MPs hold* **regular sessions called surgeries** *where they meet constituents to talk about issues of concern. If you go to a constituency surgery, it’s best to contact your MP’s office first, to find out whether you need an appointment.*](http://www.parliament.uk/get-involved/contact-your-mp/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I used the expression "political surgery" to look for past usages in Google Books. It is an indication of the contiguity of the two terms. I agree that the common term  is just "surgery" in a political context, but it appears there is no result for MPs surgery.

Comment: Google has a few for [*MP surgery*](https://wiki.openrightsgroup.org/wiki/MP_surgery) but mostly it's just *surgery* if the context is clear there's unlikely to be confusion 1. http://www.margaretgreenwood.org.uk/ and 2. http://www.davidhanson.org.uk/surgery/

Comment: I wonder how many of the references picked up by the Ngram related to political changes in the sense of "cutting out", possibly calls for the abolition of the undemocratic Rotten Boroughs. The earliest references preceded the Reform Act of 1832 and I would not have expected MPs sitting for Rotten Boroughs to have enough concern for their unenfranchised constituents to hold sugeries in the modern sense.